# SpringBoot: Running application using Maven "mvn clean compile exec:java" works fine but creating jar using "mvn clean install" throws error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, multi-tenant

I am getting the below exception which I try to run my spring boot application using `"java -jar jarname.jar"` command.

When I run the application using "**mvn clean compile exec:java**" it runs without any exceptions but after creating the jar using "**mvn clean compile -DskipTests install**" command below exception is thrown.

I also noticed a strange behavior, when I update project from my **STS** and then if I create the jar it runs perfectly fine.

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantTransactionManager' defined in class path 
resource [com/ps/main/TenantDatabaseConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'transactionManager' parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.**NoSuchBeanDefinitionException**: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: expected at least 
1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="tenantEntityManagerFactory")}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
 ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) 
~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at com.ps.main.Application.main(Application.java:22) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [deliziahr-authentication-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [deliziahr-authentication-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [deliziahr-authentication-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [deliziahr-authentication-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory'**
 available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="tenantEntityManagerFactory")}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
 ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253) 
~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
 ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: A spring boot application should started via `mvn package spring-boot:run` and not via `mvn clean compile exec:java` or via `mvn clean compile -DskipTests install` which is worse than before...please read the documentation on spring boot...

Comment: Please read the question carefully my concern is with the jar creation and not with the run command. `mvn package spring-boot:run` works fine but when I run the created jar it still throws above mentioned exception.

Comment: If you use exec-plugin to run your spring boot app you are doing wrong cause spring-boot-maven-plugin already contains everything you need. Furthermore I want to verify that you are building your jar's correctly if an `mvn package spring-boot:run` does not work your project is configured wrong. So I've read your post very carefully...

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to offend you when I said read the question carefully. Yes I understand what you are trying to say.. my point was to say when I use exec plugin or spring-boot:run my application works fine without any issues. But when I execute the jar that is created after using `mvn package spring-boot:run` it throws an error.

Comment: That's exactly what I expected. That means your configuration in your project is simply wrong. And you are doing something different than the docs are telling. So without a full project it's impossible to guess what's really wrong ...?

Comment: But sometimes the jar works and sometimes it doesn't. At first I thought Configuration must be wrong but application runs perfectly fine with `mvn package spring-boot:run' and jar works too but sometimes it doesnt. I can give you today's example when I used `mvn package spring-boot:run' application was running ok then I execute the jar using java -jar It worked fine but when I again used `mvn package spring-boot:run` and then execute the jar using java -jar it failed. I don't understand this strange behavior if configuration was wrong then it shouldn't work anytime right?

Comment: also if I update the project in STS and then if I create the jar it works 90% of the times.